# XCode 4.5.2 Linker Errors

Tags: ios, linker, unity-game-engine

I am unable build an iOS app out of XCode due to Apple Mach-O Linker Errors. Here are XCode screenshots and also my workflow:

Unity 4

- I have pro version of both Unity and the iOS extension

Vuforia 1.5.10 unity extension

XCode 4.5.2

- Architectures and Valid Architectures all set to armv7 under Build Settings (Resolved, Unity-Iphone, Unity-Iphone). However, iOS Default is grayed out and I cannot change. It is set to Standard (armv7, armv7s)

  - Keep receiving "Apple Mach-O Linker Errors" with regard to Vuforia features

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

"_markerGetId", referenced from:

```
  RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

"_qcarSetFrameFormat", referenced from:

```
  RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

"_rendererGetVideoBackgroundCfg", referenced from:

```
  RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

"_imageTrackerDestroyDataSet", referenced from:

```
  RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

"_imageTrackerActivateDataSet", referenced from:

```
  RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

"_cameraDeviceSetFlashTorchMode", referenced from:

```
  RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

"_imageTargetCreateVirtualButton", referenced from:

```
  RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

"_getProjectionGL", referenced from:

```
  RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

"_dataSetGetTrackablesOfType", referenced from:

```
  RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

"_trackerManagerDeinitTracker", referenced from:

```
  RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

"_trackerManagerInitTracker", referenced from:

```
  RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

"_rendererSetVideoBackgroundCfg", referenced from:

```
  RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

"_qcarRequiresAlpha", referenced from:

```
  RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

"_cameraDeviceStartCamera", referenced from:

```
  RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

"_rendererIsVideoBackgroundTextureInfoAvailable", referenced from:

```
  RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

"_dataSetGetNumTrackableType", referenced from:

```
  RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

"_virtualButtonIsEnabled", referenced from:

```
  RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

"_isRendererDirty", referenced from:

```
  RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

"_rendererGetVideoBackgroundTextureInfo", referenced from:

```
  RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

Comment: Are external libraries compiled to support armv7 and armv7s?

Comment: You won't get any helpful answers unless you tell us what the undefined symbols are.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

I just went with the same problem and, after couple days, I've finally solved it! Made it work with latest *Unity 4.2* and *Vuforia 2.6.7*

Few probable things that could be causing the issue:

- **Folder hierarchy**: This is the **biggest most likely point**. Leave it as it is when imported from the packagefile. If you move a single file out of its original place, with a few exceptions, you will get many errors as you've described.
- **Folder naming**: Although I apparently had no issues here, **use no spaces**. It's advised [everywhere](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/step-2-compiling-simple-project) (despite the package itself unpacking folders with spaces on it...).
- **Build Settings / Player Settings**: Again, I had no issues here. And I've tried changing them a little on an empty project, which worked with no issue. But, having the wrong setting here can cause such linker errors. **Create an open project and try around**.

To try again after changing any configuration, use `CMD + SHIFT + B` and press on **Build and Run**. It will ask where to save and, if saving on top, select **Replace**.

And good luck!